# Find last Max value / alternative to Max for Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

(Last) EDIT3:

=index(sort(filter(A:D,A:A<=DATEVALUE(A3),B:B=B3,D:D<>0),3,f‌​alse),1,3)

1. filters starting date to current date, exercise name, rep <>0.
2. sort weight by descending so highest is first row
3. index weight row

Seems to work faster, still have to drag since filter doesn't work in arrayformula. Only returns max of the day which is sufficient, technically I would like to have max leading up to that set (i.e. if date value was finer that I can filter by minute/seconds but the original data doesn't have that info). I suppose I can make another column of sequential numbers to give each row an order for comparison.

Original Question:

I'm building an exercise logger and trying to find the last MAX weight value of each exercise. The formula I have mostly works, but it's pretty slow since it compares all exercises and weight up the current cell and the sheet has close to 30000 entries.

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to index/match/sort so I can get it working in one cell arrayformula since Max doesn't work in an Array. Something like finding previous occurrence of Exercise (B:B), keep whichever value higher value of weight (C:C).

Also for the current formula, I would like to keep previous MAX weight if reps = 0 (some sort of AND IF D:D<>0). So if I fail to perform a single rep (aka rep = 0), the weight value doesn't get carried over into the calculations. Behavior highlighted in red. This seems to tie back into the find previous highest value method above and plugging it as the false condition.

sample sheet

[image]

Thank you, losing my mind trying to find "last occurrence" examples that work.

Edit: The logic for the formula in my brain seems like it should be

1. find previous entry of exercise B:B, if it doesn't exist, set maxE to current weightC (sets the first max)
2. if previous exerciseB does exist, then find if current repD is greater or equal to 1 (i.e. not 0)
3. compare current weightC to previous maxE and set current maxE to whichever is greater
4. else (when current repD is less than 1), set current MaxE to previous MaxE

EDIT 2:

@anonymous, thank you for your input.

[image]

Formula comparison above

Your formula (column F) behaves very similar to what I have (column D and in formula bar) with with a few errors (highlighted yellow). Overall, I am able to detect D<>0 (highlight red), but unable to find a way to find method to determine previous occurrence of group and adjacent value in Google Sheets. However, I have found "reverse" function that works in excel (image below) but unfortunately "=LOOKUP(2,1/" does not work in Google Sheets which still processes top down. So in Excel, the formula returns 60, which is correct, in Sheets, it will return 25.

[image]

Excel works. It finds last occurrence.

I'm going to stick with Excel for now because it works, and Google Sheets takes 20 minutes to crunch through the existing formula. Mainly I was hoping to find a method to reduce processing time or avoid using MAX since it's not compatible in array for single equation.

Comment: @diggy, By your logic, `=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(B2=B1,IF(D2<>0,MAX(C2,E1),E1), C2)))` and drag fill down, but this won't work, because there are multiple exercises arranged randomly.

Comment: @anonymous, thank you for the effort, please see edit for progress. In short, I think I found the necessary function to get things working but it is not supported in Google Sheets.

Comment: @diggy, AFAIK, Google sheets also supports LOOKUP (2,1/... ) approach.  You might wanna enter it with `ARRAYFORMULA (LOOKUP(2,... ))`

Comment: @diggy, Excel will also take the top down approach only.  It will still go through all the values and arrive at the last one.  Further more, there's SORT function in Google sheets.  You could reverse sort it and use it if necessary. Play with it. But, imo it'll be better, if you actually sort the data.  I'll be a huge improvement in performance

Comment: @anonymous, thanks for the suggestion, I have a semi working function that filters by exercise name / entries up to current date / reps <>0, sorts the output by descending, then indexes the first matching value (which should be previous largest weight <>0. It seems to process much faster, minutes instead of tens of minutes but still have to drag.

=index(sort(filter(A:D,A:A<=DATEVALUE(A3),B:B=B3,D:D<>0),3,false),1,3)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=QUERY(B:D,"Select B,max(C) where not D=0 and B is not null group by B")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am not trying to find max (when rep <> 0) for each unique exercise for the entire range, but max (when rep <> 0) for exercise on each row from beginning of the range, to that particular row. i.e.


Weight: 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4, 5
Max: 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6